# maximise file storage efficiency

Tags: file, filesystems

I have a set of large files that need to be stored and my understanding is that the number of blocks that a given file should take up is the filesize in bytes divided by the block size in bytes, then always round up if it is not a whole block.

SO, for my example, I have a file that is 41,481,854,065 bytes, and a filesystem that has 4096 bytes block size.

I work that out at 10,127,406 blocks as the theoretical minimum number of blocks. However, *du* is reporting that the file is using 11,399,100 blocks, which is giving me a massive difference of 5,208,858,624 bytes difference, which is 4.85GB on a file that is 44GB.

This seems a lot to me and I would like to try and understand why there is so much *slack space* when I could unreasonably expect there to be a maximum of 4k.

I have three questions:

1. What could be causing this huge difference?
2. How can I detect what actually does cause it?
3. Is there anything I can do to improve the efficiency and reduce the slack space?

I'm fairly sure I'm making some unreasonable assumptions somewhere, but would like to know where that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since no-one has been forthcoming, my own research and guesswork has turned up only the following options:

1. The Files are badly fragmented on the same disk.
2. The Files are spread across multiple Physical disks on a storage array.
3. The Files have been intentionally spread across multiple physical disks in order to maximise read access speed.